# Count with where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, count, where

Is there a way to have WHERE clause in COUNT ? Or how to count with some clause ?

```
select 
  a
  b,
  count(c where t1.u='UAE') as c1 
from t1
```

I am using MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? essentially i'm asking why you dont put the `where` clause where it normally goes?

Answer (score 11):

No, the syntax you have is not valid, it can be corrected by the use of a `CASE` expression.
(and I guess you have a `GROUP BY a, b` as you'd get an error otherwise).

```
select 
  a
  b,
  count(case when t1.u = 'UAE' then c else null end) as c1 
from t1 
group by a, b ;
```

Note that the `ELSE NULL` is redundant and can be removed as that is the default `ELSE` behaviour anyway:

```
select 
  a
  b,
  count(case when t1.u = 'UAE' then c end) as c1 
from t1 
group by a, b ;
```

---

There is a (SQL Standard) `FILTER` syntax that is close to your attempt but SQL Server has not yet implemented it:

```
select 
  a
  b,
  count(c) filter (where t1.u = 'UAE') as c1 
from t1 
group by a, b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
  DISTINCT
    a.a
    ,a.b
    ,b.c1
FROM
    t1 a
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                a
                ,b
                ,COUNT(u) AS c1
            FROM
                t1
            WHERE
                u = 'UAE'
            GROUP BY
                a
                ,b
            ) b
ON  a.a = b.a AND
    a.b = b.b
```

Just another way of doing it.